# xcode fails to recognise @property but it is correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Xcode failing to recognize `@property` in detail controller.

.m file of ViewController2:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

        // load the image.

        NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedIndexPath.row];
        NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"JPG"];
        UIImage *image2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

       Detail_ViewController_Biffy *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    Detail_ViewController_Biffy.**image = image;**  <--- fails [property 'image'not found on object of type 'detail_ViewController_Biffy'
    }
}
```

.h file of detail_view

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController_Biffy : ViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

@end
```

Tried to change the import `ViewController.h` to `ViewController_Biffy.h` but causes more errors.

If you need further info, let me know.

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in your header.

Comment: Where is Detail_ViewController_Biffy defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get a property from a class rather than the instance. Try

```
Detail_ViewController_Biffy *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
detailViewController.image = image
```

Also the type you have says detail_ViewController2 which is not anywhere in your code

Comment: Edited the code - apologies! My mistake. I Tried your suggested code, still says use of undeclared identifier even though it is identified as shown in the original code. It seems to like suggesting previous names that were associated with the property... :S

Comment: Edit the code in the question and answer the last sentance here

Comment: Many thanks for your repsonse though the second answer solved it.

Answer (score 1):

First: `image` is a property not a class method so you would need to access it:

```
detailViewController.image =
```

Secondly `image` in your `prepareForSegue:sender:` does not exist. I am guessing you are trying to set your property to `image2` which you create a couple lines up. In that case the failing line of code would look like:

```
detailViewController.image = image2;
```

All properties are accessed through instances of classes. Although you may not know it, you are already creating a detailViewController instance on your line:

```
Detail_ViewController_Biffy *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

Comment: Yup, that worked, now getting a Mach-O Liner Error, which is because I've copied some of the same code already as I'm trying to have separate name types appear in separate cells on separate view controllers..

Comment: I am guessing that your linker error is caused by a class you dropped into your project that was not targeted properly. This may be beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: Cheers to both of your suggestions got over that hurdle!! Brilliant!!!  Many thanks